# How to select rows using IN clause and zerofill field in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `ss_highlight_ids` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `highlight_id` int(10) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000000000',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `highlight_id_UNIQUE` (`highlight_id`),
    KEY `highlight_id_INDEX` (`highlight_id`) COMMENT ''
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13580 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

and I like to use the IDs of another table to select all rows having the same id in the `ss_highlight_ids`.`highlight_id`.

The query I use to select the rows is the following:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `ss_highlight_ids` AS `hi`
WHERE
    `hi`.`highlight_id` IN(
        SELECT 
            LPAD( `p`.`ID`, 10, '0' ) AS `ID`
        FROM 
            ss_posts AS `p`
        WHERE
            `p`.`post_type` = 'football-highlights'
            AND `p`.`post_date` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    )
```

but unfortunately does not return anything. So the question is if I am doing something wrong or if I should do something else.

Please note that I have data related in my DB, and I have try instead of `IN` to use `=` with a single `ID` value and works, but doesn't work with the `IN` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the lpad also for zerofill column because i think the zero fill is use only for rendering but not for evalutation

```
SELECT  *
FROM  `ss_highlight_ids` AS `hi`
WHERE
lpad(`hi`.`highlight_id`, 10 , '0')  IN(
    SELECT  LPAD( `p`.`ID`, 10, '0' ) 
    FROM  ss_posts AS `p`
    WHERE `p`.`post_type` = 'football-highlights'
    AND `p`.`post_date` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
)
```

Comment: It seems like not work :( I have try it and still not working :(

Comment: then try getting the result from the subselect and check if there are proper data .. and try remuving the alias to form sub select ..  i have update the answer

Comment: @MerianosNikos  was the alias?

Comment: The alias of subselect or improper data?